# Javascript getDate Function returns wrong day of the month

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have a function in JavaScript and its returning the wrong day of the month, please help me find out what is the issue.

here is the code:

```
function getFormattedDate(date) {
   var year = date.getFullYear();
   var month = (1 + date.getMonth()).toString();
   month = month.length > 1 ? month : '0' + month;
   var day = date.getDate().toString();
   //condition ? value-if-true : value-if-false
   day = day.length > 1 ? day : '0' + day;
   return month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
 }
```

I am passing/reading the following date from Oracle Database: 
31-MAR-1944 - This is how it looks in the oracle table.

I get the following returned value: 03/30/1944

The goal of this function is just to return the same date in different format such as MM/DD/YYYY.

What am i doing wrong ??

Thanks

Comment: It's a timezone issue

Comment: Your function works fine for me. Can you show how you parse the date to js date object?

Comment: I don't parse the date object. All I do is pass it into a script processor and code the following:

var dateArr = input1[0]; // this is the input from snapshot from database
var bnfdobArr = new Date(dateArr);
var results = "";
// This someday is equal to 01/01/0001
someday = new Date();
someday.setFullYear(0001, 0, 01);

if (bnfdobArr > someday){
  results = getFormattedDate(bnfdobArr);
}

output1 = results; //return output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these and I think you will get some information that will help you:

```
getFormattedDate(new Date('31-MAR-1944 GMT'));
getFormattedDate(new Date('31-MAR-1944'));
```

The first one works "incorrectly" because it is parses that particular date format `dd-mmm-yyyy` string into the GMT time zone and you are apparently some x hours behind GMT, GMT-x. However, the second one works "correctly" because the time is in your own time zone before the function's calculations begin. In fact, if you just examine the basic date value that is getting passed to the function, you may learn all you need. On my computer here's an example:

```
new Date('31-MAR-1944 GMT')
// Thu Mar 30 1944 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

To translate the date out of your current time zone and back into the original time zone (this gets tricky to say depending on how you look at it), you'll need to do something such as use a different format, remove the time zone from the date string, or account for time zone differences between computers in your organization. You could see if using the `getUtcDate` and `getUtcMonth` functions do the job for you, or you could do explicit time zone calculation.

Start with your date object, then `getTimezoneOffset()` on it. This returns a number in minutes of reverse sign to the GMT offset in hours. Convert the timezone offset of the server time into minutes and appropriately add or subtract. THEN do your date math to get a formatted date.

Comment: I am still getting the same answer. So I have an update. In the Oracle table it looks like 31-MAR-1944 but my snapshot is reading it as Mar 31, 1944 12:00:00 AM. Does this make a difference ?? So basically my input is Mar 31, 1944 12:00:00 AM. Thx

Comment: I stand by my comment. You need to look at the date value that is getting passed to the function. Can you debug, and put a breakpoint in the code so you can examine the date value at run time?

Comment: This is the date value getting passed in to the function at run time.
Thu Mar 30 1944 23:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)

thx

Comment: So what is the confusion about why a date of Mar 30 is returning a string for March 30?

Comment: But the value i am reading is Mar 31, 1944 12:00:00 AM from the snapshot, therefore it has to be a time zone issue. maybe ??

Comment: for me it gives 31, so yes, it is timezone problem. The string has timezon info, and for some places for earth in that time moment was 31th, for other - 30th.

Comment: The problem is clearly in the code between where you're reading in the string and where you're passing a date to this function. The function has nothing to do with the problem. Ask a new question with more information: the data type format of the database column, how it's being converted to a date, and so on.